# How to use this script in python

Tags: python

I found [this script](https://github.com/NadalVRoMa/PyLibGen) on github to download books from [Library Genesis](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/), but I can't understand the usage methods.

According to specifications the command is `pylibgen.py [-h] [-t | -a | -p | -y] search [search ...]`

where

```
positional arguments:
  search           search term

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  -t, --title      get books from the specified title
  -a, --author     get books from the specified author
  -p, --publisher  get books from the specified publisher
  -y, --year       get books from the specified year
```

The problem is author not provided a functional example to people not so acquainted. Can anyone help?

Comment: Be there a part in `[-h] [-t | -a | -p | -y] search [search ...]` that confounds thy mind? (You could brute force your terminal your terminal with trial-and-error, you know. :P)

Comment: This is a silly question, you need to presumably use `-t "Great Expectations" -a Dickens`. But I can't be sure. Check further into the usage on the GitHub page and try different args etc. If not this needs to be brought up on GitHub issues or similar, not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author did provide the functional example as you can see in the first line of the screenshot in the `README.md` in the git repository. You can use this script in a way that you type `python3 pylibgen.py` and then add a term that you would enter in the search bar on the actual website. if you want to add additional search parameters, then there are the flags you can use. For example, if you want to filter results by the author just add `-a some_author` to the script call. So now the whole script run would be:

`python3 pylibgen.py some_term -a some_author`

You can swap `some_term` and `some_author` with the terms and authors you want to search/filter by. The same goes for all the other flags and criteria. If you want to add multiple filters just add another flag. Let's say you want to filter by year also. Your script run would then be

`python3 pylibgen.py some_term -a some_author -y some_year`